# Qemu Raspberry Pi to Windows file transfer PUTTY

Tags: ssh, putty, qemu

[image]

Im logged in through putty for an ssh with the raspberry pi qemu on windows. I want to get the .tgz file from the qemu to my windows so i can submit the file as my homework but i dont know how to save it to my pc!

I know it's a stupid question but Please help! my hw is due really soon, i have it all done but it's pathetic that i cant figure out how to access it

Comment: This question does not seem to involve a Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using putty it should include a secure copy client called PSCP.

You can read the [documentation from earth.li](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter5.html) to get more info. But the basics are as such, as quoted in section 5.2.1:

> To receive (a) file(s) from a remote server:
>
> pscp [options] [user@]host:source target
>
> So to copy the file /etc/hosts from the server example.com as user fred to the file c:\temp\example-hosts.txt, you would type:
>
> pscp fred@example.com:/etc/hosts c:\temp\example-hosts.txt

The [options] part may require you to specify your ssh private key location, or your ssh password. Depending on how you have set up sshd on the pi.

Of course, if you use passwords, it may just ask you for it when the command is entered. But if it does not, and it fails try to find the password option param and send it with the command.

EDIT:

As a side note, in the future you should use the Windows Subsystem for Linux if you are using windows 10 (as your screenshot appears to be). It will allow you to take full advantage of an ubuntu environment in windows. Making these sorts of tasks ***a lot*** easier.

See MSDN instructions on it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide). It's made my windows life much better. Keep in mind though, the real tool (the one PSCP is based off of) is scp. Same command, just not putty's.